# Styling in index file not showing under rewritten URL

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have a website that redirects to different pages using SEO friendly URLs. For instance the rewritten `mysite.com/login` is actually `mysite.com/index.php?login`. I have that working fine, but it doesn't include the styles and script inclusions I have in my index.php

I've tried to do `<script>console.log("Test")</script>` in the index.php, and it's not showing in the console on the rewritten page.

**Here is my index.php**

```php
<?php
echo '<script>console.log("Test")</script>';
//Check for more GET variables.
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$split = explode("?", $url);
if (isset($split[1])) {
    $newvarsarray = explode("&", $split[1]);
    foreach ($newvarsarray as $newvar) {
        $keyandvalue = explode("=", $newvar);
        if (isset($keyandvalue[1])) {
            $_GET[$keyandvalue[0]] = $keyandvalue[1];
        } else {
            $_GET[$keyandvalue[0]] = '';
        }

    }
} else {
    //No additional vars, leave $_GET alone.
}


include_once 'globalheader.html';
include_once 'header.html';

//This is the area where we handle the different states of the webpage and import them into here
if (empty($_GET)) {
    //Main homepage
    include_once 'mainpage.html';
} else if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
    //Login page
    include_once 'login.html';
} else if (isset($_GET['register'])) {
    //Register page
    include_once 'register.html';
} else if (isset($_GET['profile'])) {
    //Profile page
}

include_once 'footer.html';
include_once 'globalfooter.html';
?>
```

**Here is the style import of my globalheader.html**

```html
  <!--Global css imports-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/globalstyle.css">
```

**Here is my .htaccess if it will help**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?login [NC]
    RewriteRule ^register$ index.php?register [NC]
</IfModule>
```

It should include the CSS as normal, but instead the page has no styling and is just default browser styles.

Comment: is your path good?

Comment: It appears to be good - if I go to it in a web browser I get the file. But it seems like it isn't just not including the styles, but not including any of the index.php besides where it is told to include its page from the `$_GET` variable.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<base href="">` tag to your globalheader.html? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base